# Postman does not have cookie parameter

Tags: postman

I read a bit about adding a cookie to a postman request.
I found a tutorial but... my postman does not have the "cookie" button there.
It should be in the upper right corner next to the "Code" orange button. I searched for a topic how to add it, but couldn't find any solution. Any help will be greatly appreciated.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2sAH.png)

Comment: which version do you use ? app or chrome ?

Comment: chrome. I found a nice workaround anyway.

Comment: cool :). don't hesitate to share it ...

Comment: yep of course :) You can simply use the request Headers section. There are some records - usually "Content-Type"-application/json, Authorization-.., etc.. Just add one line with key: "Cookie" and value in the format: "cookieKey=cookieValue" (in my case the whole line is: Cookie: tempSessionID=8db1055fea5b112ed7310ak5367fd4eb6953bff81e97ee0dc425f8fe7c81be3c)